# Is Google+ takeout including photos and videos already in my Google Photos app?

Tags: google-plus, google-photos, google-takeout, online-backup

Since Google+ is about to close, I downloaded the takeout files. What called my attention is that the files downloaded are huge, 2GB and 0.6GB. I searched for one or two videos included in the takeout and they are not in my Google Photos.

Is that including photos and videos already included in my Photos app?